# Play a sound file on repeat in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I have had success playing sounds by pressing a button, by using the following code. However, I'd like to press a button and have that sound play in a loop/infinitely. How is this achieved? I'd also like to achieve pause/play functionality as well. Thanks in advance.

```swift
@IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    playSound(soundName: sender.currentTitle!)
}
        
        
func playSound(soundName: String) { 
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundName, withExtension: "wav")
    player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
    player.play()
} 
// End of Play Sound
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default **AVAudioPlayer** plays its audio from start to finish then stops, but we can control how many times to make it loop by setting its [**numberOfLoops**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1386071-numberofloops) property. For example, to make your audio play three times in total, you’d write this:

```
 player.numberOfLoops = 3
```

if you want the infinite loop then use

```
 player.numberOfLoops =  -1
```

for e.g

```
  func playSound(soundName: String) { //
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundName, withExtension: "wav")
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        player.numberOfLoops =  -1 // set your count here 
        player.play()

    } // End of Play Sound
```

Answer (score 1):

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

```
    func startBackgroundMusic() {
        if let bundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Guru_Nanak_Sahib_Ji", ofType: "mp3") {
            let backgroundMusic = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: bundle)
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:backgroundMusic as URL)
                guard let audioPlayer = audioPlayer else { return }
                audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1 // for infinite times
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retain the player.  Then in the player's completion delegate callback, start playing again.  Or stop the player at any time, since you've retained a reference to it.